# Visually select a few lines given start and end positions in vimscript

Tags: vimscript, visual-mode

I want to write a function that will remove blank lines given a set of visually selected lines by the user.

After removing the blank lines, I want the input lines still be visually selected.

How can I achieve this? Here is the code that removes blank lines:

```
function! RemoveBlankLines() range
    exe a:firstline.",".a:lastline."g/^\s*$/d"
endfunction
command! -range=% RemoveBlankLines <line1>,<line2>call RemoveBlankLines()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have said to use `'[` and `']` marks, but alas each command executed by `:global` is messing with them.
However, you only need to know the new last line, as the first line won't change. `']` won't be enough as well.

I see several solution:

1. Mark the last line. Cons: it'll modify a mark -> this may mess the marks the end user is using -> not good
2. have `:g` count how many lines you have removed. Cons: more verbose code
3. Don't reselect at the end of the command (which will be odd if it wasn't called from the visual mode), but at the end of a visual mapping.

   `xnoremap µ :RemoveBlankLine<cr>gv`

   And let the user manually reselect  after the call to the command -- I'm not sure you'll be able to use `mode()` to check whether you are in visual mode to conditionally reselect.

Anyway, back to your exact question, I'll do it this way (2.):

```
function! s:RemoveBlankLines() range
    let cpt = 0
    silent exe a:firstline.','.a:lastline.'g/^\s*$/d_|let cpt+=1'
    exe a:firstline
    normal! V
    exe (a:lastline-cpt)
endfunction

command! -range=% RemoveBlankLines <line1>,<line2>call s:RemoveBlankLines()
```